# Calculated column - Date and minutes/seconds from Modified column

Tags: calculated-column

In a library my calculated column calculates what date Monday is the week after a document is `last Modified`.

```
=Modified-WEEKDAY(Modified,2)+8
```

I also want to add the minutes and seconds (not the hours):

```
=Modified-WEEKDAY(Modified,2)+8&" "&TEXT(Modified,"mm:ss")
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I get '`42856.4667361111 12:06`' instead of the date and time (minus the hours). What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You will need to convert the first part to date format:

=TEXT(Modified-WEEKDAY(Modified,2)+8,"dd/mm/yy")&" "&TEXT(Modified,"mm:ss")

[More information here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?CorrelationId=4b7b05f0-675a-439d-adc9-a99b35004486&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010062580)